# Xamarin.Forms Mac AuthenticationContinuationHelper

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac, azure-ad-msal

Anyone try using Microsoft.Identy.Client package with Xamarin.Forms in MacOS project?

I try to implement OpenUrl method according to sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2/tree/master but in AppDelegate in MacOS project VS cannot see AuthenticationContinuationHelper class. Microsoft.Identity.Client class is limited:
[Microsoft.Identity.Client in MacOS Project not show all items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbpGZ.png)

At .Droid and .iOS project everything work properly.

Anyone was handled with this?

Answer (score 0):

So there is a video from [Build 2018](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2018/THR5006) as well as the [Slide Deck](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http%3a%2f%2fvideo.ch9.ms%2fsessions%2fc1f9c808-82bc-480a-a930-b340097f6cc1%2fBuildingANativeApplicationUsingXamarin.pptx) that discuss that. You need to make sure in your nuget settings you have the "show pre-release packages" checked, and then install the Microsoft.Identity.Client. I had the same issue until I did that, installed the nugets, cleaned and rebuilt the solution.

[image: Nuget Settings]

The problem with Xamarin.mac is that the library does not currently, nor does it sound like it will any time soon support the Xamarin.mac platform.  This is mentioned in [Open Issue #522](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/522) on the GitHub repository, after some further reading into it. That was dated on February 20th, with no news since then, so I don't believe they have it on their roadmap. Must be something with the way MacOS handles the brewer handoff, let alone the MacOS was just recently supported by some of their services in Azure, which makes me think there is not enough market share there yet in this space?

Comment: Louis, have you this problem also in **Xamarin.Mac** project?

Comment: Yes, I had to do the same for the Xamarin.Mac project in order for it to show up in the IntelliSense in Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect some new research I discovered. The product team is not supporting macOS at this time, and do not have it on the roadmap either.

Comment: Yes, MacOS is niche environment. According to your first respond I understood that you handle up with this problem. Thank you for the information, after all.

Comment: Sure thing. Not sure what the difference in macOS would be that would prevent this from being available. Neat bug though.